# XSLT 1.0 Adding element to multple matches

Tags: api, xslt, match, xslt-1.0, element

I'm new to XSLT.
I'm trying to add element to multiple objects received from API.
So here is an example XML received from API:

```
<array xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms" name="orders">
   <object xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms">
      <bunch of info here 1st order>
   </object>
   <object xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms">
      <bunch of info here 2nd order>
   </object>
....
</array>
```

Input is like this and I need output like this:

```
<array xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms" name="orders">
   <object xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms">
      <Location>USA</Location>
      <bunch of info here 1st order>
   </object>
   <object xmlns="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms">
      <Location>USA</Location>
      <bunch of info here 2nd order>
   </object>
....
</array>
```

This means I need to insert a location element to every bfa:object.

I tried this way but no success.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bfa:object">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <Location>USA</Location>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sap="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="sap:object">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:element name="Locations" namespace="urn:com.sap.b1i.bizprocessor:bizatoms">USA</xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B73

Comment: thanks your suggestion.
But the problem is in the output i'm receiving raw data not xml and at last Location is inserted. By raw data i mean the values of elements are combined.

Comment: @КоунтЗеро Without seeing your real input and output we can't really help more.

Comment: the input is pretty long 39000 chars and what i can say is XPath is /vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role='S']/* there will be my input shown at top. And here is what im getting after trying your solution input: https://ibb.co/LYj7ht5 output: https://ibb.co/LYj7ht5
https://ibb.co/dBqSNJZ